# I can access anything but Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

I can go to any other website (Google or not), however I cannot access [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) regardless of what account name I use. It redirects me to https://www.google.com/analytics/web/ which is a plain white screen. Is there any advice that someone can offer?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The site works fine for me in [Google Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95346).
Here is how I would go about troubleshooting:

1. Clear your web browser history, cookies, temp files and cache and try again
2. Try a different web browser than you are currently using
3. Sign up for Google Analytics (you need to that separately)
4. Report back here if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I you use the Adblock extension, make sure you add the domain https://www.google.com/analytics/ into the exception list.